# Change of fluid density with change of cross sectional area

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

If we take an incompressible fluid flowing through a tube with gradually shrinking radius,the streamlines must come closer,thus density of streamlines must increase,but since fluid is incompressible,thus the density of the fluid in a particular streamline must decrease but this again contradicts the assumption that fluid density is constant.........can somebody please explain this apparent paradox?

Comment: You seem to be confusing streamline density with fluid density. Close packing of streamlines indicates faster flow rate for an incompressible fluid, without any change in fluid density.

Answer (score 2):

With an incompressible fluid the flow rate must be the same at all points in the pipe. That is, if we measure the mass per second, or equivalently the volume per second, passing a point on the pipe this must be the same along the pipe.

The volume flow rate is the cross sectional area of the pipe times the flow velocity - multiply by the density to get the mass flow rate. So if you reduce the area of the pipe the flow velocity has to increase and vice versa. When your streamlines converge the liquid flows faster, and when the stream lines diverge the liquid flows slower.

Comment: Yeah thats fine,but sir,when the fluid flows faster the cross sectional area becomes smaller and the streamlines come closer.......now if we want to calculate density of the fluid at that cross section(which due to the assumption is constant),since the streamline density(ie the no. of streamlines per unit area) in that area is more,so the density of the fluid in that streamline must decrease at that region......but this cant happen......this is my problem

Comment: @Randomguy: I guess a small parcel of incompressible fluid entering a faster-moving narrower section of pipe becomes smaller radially *but longer axially* - the total volume and hence density of the parcel are not altered by the change in shape of the parcel.